# Docker-compose wouldn't start on Sagemaker's Notebook instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-sagemaker

Docker-compose seems to have stopped working on Sagemaker Notebook instances. When running `docker-compose up` I encounter the following error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
    command_func()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
    enabled_profiles=get_profiles_from_options(options, environment)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
    verbose=verbose, version=api_version, context=context, environment=environment
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
    environment=environment, tls_version=get_tls_version(environment)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
    client = APIClient(use_ssh_client=not use_paramiko_ssh, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
    'Error while fetching server API version: {0}'.format(e)
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=60, read=60, total=None), but it must be an int, float or None
```

I can start Docker containers as usual.

```
sh-4.2$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.15.14
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Tue Sep 28 19:55:40 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.15.14
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Tue Sep 28 19:57:35 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0
  GitCommit:        %runc_commit
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

But `docker-compose` wouldn't work...

```
sh-4.2$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.6.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who (might) have encountered the same issue, here's the fix:

1). Install the newest version of docker-compose:

```
sh-4.2$ sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sh-4.2$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

2). Change your `PATH` accordingly (since docker-compose is installed using `conda` and is picked up first) or use `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` onwards:

```
sh-4.2$ PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
sh-4.2$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
docker-py version: 5.0.0
CPython version: 3.7.10
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0l  10 Sep 2019
```

Perhaps, the issue is related to this:

> On August 9, 2021 the Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab open source software projects announced 2 security concerns that could impact Amazon Sagemaker Notebook Instance customers.
>
> Sagemaker has deployed updates to address these concerns, and we recommend customers with existing notebook sessions to stop and restart their notebook instance(s) to benefit from these updates. Notebook instances launched after August 10, 2021, when updates were deployed, are not impacted by this issue and do not need to be restarted.